What is the centre of mass of subset of a simplex with simple linear bounds
Let $\mathcal{R} \subset \mathcal{S}$ be the sub-region of the probability simplex with dimension $k-1$ defined by:
$$
\mathcal{R} = \{\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^k  | \sum_{i = 1}^k x_i = 1, 0 \leq x_1 \leq b_1, \dots, 0 \leq x_k \leq b_k,\}
$$
for upper bounds $b_1, b_2, \dots, b_k$.
Is there a simple formula for the centre of mass of $\mathcal{R}$, given that geometrically it is a hyper-polygon? I am guessing there isn't because I cannot find anything beyond the 2d and 3d case: https://paulbourke.net/geometry/polygonmesh/centroid.pdf
